# Minimum tabstop of 2

Tags: linux, gtk, indentation, text-editor

I have some code written in Debian >= 9 (Gnome 3) with gedit.

The tabs there work as usual:

Given a tabstop of 8, and I'll call the first column 0,

a tab at column `8 * n + m` where `0 <= m < 8` takes you to column `8 * (n + 1)`.

---

But, when I use Manjaro (XFCE), either with Mousepad (default) or Gedit (installed by me),

a tab at column `8 * n + m` depends on `m`:

- if `m <= 6` it takes you to `8 * (n + 1)` as expected,
- but if `m == 7`, it takes you to `8 * (n + 2)`.

Basically this is behaving as if the minimum length of a tab is 2.

Why is that weird behaviour and how can it be worked around?

Comment: More modern text editors like CudaText don't have this problem?

Comment: @Prog1020 I don't know that editor.  `pacman -Ss cuda` only shows GPU things.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the status bar tells the right column number, but visually it behaves wrongly, so it will probably be a bug in Manjaro or XFCE or GTK.  I'll just report it to Manjaro.